# How to get previous data of object in django save model method

Tags: django, django-models

Lets say we have an object `myobj` which has fields `f1`, `f2`.
Initially the fields are set to `1` and `2` and saved having `pk=1`

Now, I am calling it again something like this:

```
myobj.f1 = 11
myobj.f2 = 22
myobj.save()
```

while the model method is `save(self, *args, **kwargs)`
I know, we can pass our own variables to it, override the method, do what ever we want..

Is there anyway that we can know previous data of the object? using some built-in arguments?

Answer (score 6):

There isn't any built-in way to get old data in `save()` method. You will have to do query the db.
Something like this:

```
class MyModel(Model):
   ...
   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if self.pk:
          old_obj = MyModel.objects.get(pk=self.pk)

       #use old_obj for something

       ...
```